# Money Business Problem

Tags: statistics

Dan's DVD discount dungeon is going out of business and selling al of its DVDs. The first customer bought 1/6 of all the dvds plus 1; the second buyer again took 1/6 of the remaining DVDs plus 2; the third buyer bought 1/6 of the remaining DVDs plus 3, and so on. When Dan had sold all of the DVDs, he figured out that surprisingly each customer had purchased the same amount of DVDs. How many DVDs did each customer buy and what was Dan's takings if he sold each DVD for $5 each?

Answer (score 1):

Since each customer had purchased the same amount of DVDs, for the first two we have:
$$
\frac{n}{6}+1=\frac{1}{6}\left(n-\frac{n}{6}-1 \right)+2
$$
and solving for $n$ , that is the initial number of DVDs, we find $n=30$, so each customer purchased $6$ DVDs and the total gain is $30 \times 5$